# How to disable twitter bootstrap email validation popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form field of type email for logging in. We also allow users to log in with their nicknames and phone numbers.

The problem is that Twitter bootstrap automatically blocks the form submit if the format in the email field is not email (doesn't contain say '@').

Is there any way to disable this twitter .js binding on clicking my "Sign in" button?

[image]

Been googling around for some 2 hours now and couldn't find any solutions so I would greatly appreciate any answers!

Comment: simply use `novalidate` tag in form, or change `type="email"` to `type="text"` and lose keyboard suggestions in mobile devices

Answer (score 6):

### Text type is bad UX for email

```html
<input type="text" />
```

This text type is not bad. But in the mobile web page, this `<input>` tag will display keyboard for just normal [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) not [email](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email).
What did it mean? Mobile phone's keyboard did not show `@`, so users should swipe keyboard to type `@`. And they can not use [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete). This is bad ux.

### Solution

Use [novalidate="novalidate"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) attribute in your `<form>` tag. This attribute skip validation when submitted. Here's examples.

```html
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_user">
  ...
</form>
```

If you use rails ERB simple-form, then you can use [novalidate](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#html-5-notice) like this.

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, html: { novalidate: true }) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

### References

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/forms#html5_input_types

Answer (score 1):

Simply use html without email attribute:

```
<input type"email" /><!--will block-->
<input type="text" /><!--will not block-->
```

Comment: I know but since the majority of users log in with email I'd like to make their experience smooth on mobile with appropriate keyboard shown (with the @ sign). Thanks for answering though!

Comment: with type text will also accept @ as email....so, you need to use without validating or validating you can use text type....

Comment: Does type="text" also display keyboard on smart phones with an @ sign?